# How can TextView be aligned right next to a Buttin in LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml

I tried to find a solution but I wasn't be able. The question is simple, how align a `TextView` and a Button in a `LinearLayout`.

Something like this:

[image]

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Subtitle" />

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you want to align them?

Comment: @nipun.birla edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set

> `android:orientation="horizontal"`
>   in your LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="my edit text"/>
    <Button
        android:text="Add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**this will work in your case**
**thanks**

Answer (score 0):

Replace in your LinearLayout orientation

```
    android:orientation="vertical"
```

to

```
    android:orientation="horizontal"
```